# React Native Multi Page Form with Formik Passing Props down to Component

Tags: react-native, formik

I m trying to create a multi page form using Formik and React Native

Using the state and array approach, I am able to render multi pages. However, to use formik, i need to pass the props down to my component namely Page1, Page2, Page3

Anyone has any idea how can this be achieved?

Im trying to pass props down to Page1.js in order to use props.handleChange, props.handBlur, props.values.... with Formik

Thanks in advance

**WizardScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { Formik } from "formik";

import Input from "./Input";
import { Page1 } from "./Page1";
import { Page2 } from "./Page2";
import { Page3 } from "./Page3";

const pages = [<Page1 />, <Page2 />, <Page3 />];
class WizardScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    page: 0
  };

  _handleSubmit = async (values, bag) => {
    try {
      console.log(values);
    } catch (error) {
      bag.setSubmitting(false);
      bag.setErrors(error);
    }
  };

  _nextPage = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ page: state.page + 1 }));
  };

  render() {
    const { container, buttonStyle } = styles;

    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ name: "", email: "", info: "" }}
        onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
      >
        {props => (
          <View style={container}>
            {pages[this.state.page]}
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Input"
              onChangeText={props.handleChange("email")}
              onBlur={props.handleBlur("email")}
              value={props.values.email}
            />
            {this.state.page === pages.length - 1 ? (
              <Button
                style={buttonStyle}
                onPress={props.handleSubmit}
                title="Submit"
              />
            ) : (
              <Button
                title="Next Page"
                style={buttonStyle}
                onPress={this._nextPage}
              />
            )}
          </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    );
  }
}
```

**Page1.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export const Page1 = props => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Text>Page 1</Text>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: @hendry_lim How did you eventually solve this? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: In the end, i did not use that approach. I think using that approach is suitable for web, but not react native. I used another approach for the multi page wizard with react native. I have some codes which u can reference - under wizard folder... https://github.com/myhendry/mobile/tree/master/src/wizard

Comment: @hendry_lim. Thank you for your response. I am actually using the wizard example but I have problem passing values from a custom component into the wizard. Could you take a look at it? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493071/how-to-pass-values-from-a-component-into-formik-multi-step-form-wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493071/how-to-pass-values-from-a-component-into-formik-multi-step-form-wizard) . Thanks

Comment: @hendry_lim thank you for referencing your Github repo. I was able to find there what I needed to be able to complete my form.

Comment: Great to hear it's of help