# How to pass values from a component into Formik multi-step form wizard?

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-bootstrap-typeahead

As the title said.
I have a stateless component based on `react-bootstrap-typeahead`  and a form wizard based on the [formik multi-step wizard example](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/examples/MultistepWizard.js) found in the docs.

However, I am unable to pass the values I got from the `typeahead` component into `formik`. I can't access `setFieldValue`.

```
    const FormElements = setFieldValue => (
        <Wizard
          initialValues={FORM_VALUES}
          onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
            sleep(300).then(() => {
              window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
              actions.setSubmitting(false);
            });
          }}
        >
          <Wizard.Page>
            <GoogleMapsPlaceLookup
              value={location => {
                console.log("I got the value correctly from my child: ", location);
              }}
            />
          </Wizard.Page>
        </Wizard>
    );

    export default FormElements;
```

How do I inject this value into `Formik`, so it can be processed `onSubmit`. Any pointer or help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Formik author here...

[In the example, the `<Wizard />` component renders `<Formik>`](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/examples/MultistepWizard.js#L57) so the `setFieldValue` in your `FormElements` function is not actually in the correct scope. If you need access to `setFieldValue` within one of your wizard's pages, you can get it out of a custom [`<Field>`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field), using [`connect()`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/connect) higher order component with a custom component, or directly from Formik context using [`<FormikConsumer>`](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/src/connect.tsx#L8) render prop.

My suggestion would be to use Formik's `<Field>` component with a render prop like so:

```js
const FormElements = () => (
  <Wizard
    initialValues={FORM_VALUES}
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
      sleep(300).then(() => {
        window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        actions.setSubmitting(false);
      });
    }}
  >
    <Wizard.Page>
      <Field name="location">
        {({ field, form }) => (
          <GoogleMapsPlaceLookup
            value={field.value /* make sure to somehow connect Formik's stored value state to the input */}
            onChange={location => {
              console.log('I got the value correctly from my child: ', location);               
              // Manually set Formik values.location and trigger validation
              form.setFieldValue('location', location);
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Field>
    </Wizard.Page>
  </Wizard>
);
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Could you please consider adding this to `formik`'s documentation? Searching around the web, I found so many unanswered questions similiar to this.