# How to set values in a multi-step Formik form with components that implement useField()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I'm implementing the [multi-step wizard example](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/master/examples/MultistepWizard.js) with Material-UI components and it works well with the [`useField()` hook](https://formik.org/docs/api/useField) but I cannot figure out how to bring [`setFieldValue()`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void) into scope, so I can use it from a wizard step.

I've seen suggestions to use the [`connect()` higher-order component](https://formik.org/docs/api/connect) but I have no idea how to do that.

Here is a snippet of my code: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-multi-step-set-value-lft8f?file=/src/App.js), and the use case:

A wizard step has some optional fields that can be shown/hidden using a [Material-UI `Switch`](https://material-ui.com/components/switches). I would like the values in the optional fields to be cleared when the switch is toggled off.

I.e.

1. Toggle switch on.
2. Enter data in Comments field.
3. Toggle switch off.
4. Comments value is cleared.
5. Toggle switch on.
6. Comments field is empty.

Hoping someone can help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517336/15982065) the other day but discarded it because I couldn't get it working.
It does actually work but I'm in two minds as to whether it's the right approach.

```
const handleOptionalChange = (form) => {
  setOptional(!optional)
  form.setFieldValue('optionalComments', '', false)
}
```

```
<FormGroup>
  <FormControlLabel
    control={
      // As this element is not a Formik field, it has no access to the Formik context.
      // Wrap with Field to gain access to the context.
      <Field>
        {({ field, form }) => (
          <Switch
            checked={optional}
            onChange={() => handleOptionalChange(form)}
            name="optional"
            color="primary"
          />
        )}
      </Field>
    }
    label="Optional"
  />
</FormGroup>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-multi-step-set-value-context-wrapper-sezzs).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-multi-step-set-value-forked-4bt78). I forked your CodeSandbox.

I tried to follow your code as closely as possible and ended up not using `WizardStep`. The `step` variable is returning a React component that is a child to `Formik`. `Formik` is rendered with props e.g. `setFieldValue`, which can be passed down to its children. In order to pass the `setFieldValue` as a prop to `step`, I had to use `cloneElement()` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement), which allows me to clone the `step` component and add props to it as follows.

```
// FormikWizard.js
<Formik
    initialValues={snapshot}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    validate={step.props.validate}
>
    {(formik) => (
        <Form>
            <DialogContent className={classes.wizardDialogContent}>
                <Stepper
                  className={classes.wizardDialogStepper}
                  activeStep={stepNumber}
                  alternativeLabel
                >
                  {steps.map((step) => (
                    <Step key={step.props.name}>
                      <StepLabel>{step.props.name}</StepLabel>
                    </Step>
                  ))}
                </Stepper>
                <Box
                  className={classes.wizardStepContent}
                  data-cy="wizardStepContent"
                >
                  {React.cloneElement(step, {
                      setFieldValue: formik.setFieldValue
                  })}
                </Box>
              </DialogContent>
              <DialogActions
                className={classes.wizardDialogActions}
                data-cy="wizardDialogActions"
              >
                <Button onClick={handleCancel} color="primary">
                  Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button
                  disabled={stepNumber <= 0}
                  onClick={() => handleBack(formik.values)}
                  color="primary"
                >
                  Back
                </Button>
                <Button
                  disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
                  type="submit"
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                >
                  {isFinalStep ? "Submit" : "Next"}
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

To access the `setFieldValue` prop in the child component, in `App.js`, I created a new component called `StepOne` and used it to wrap around the inputs, instead of using `WizardStep`. Now I am able to access `setFieldValue` and use it in the `handleOptionalChange` function.

```
// App.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import FormikTextField from "./FormikTextField";
import { Wizard, WizardStep } from "./FormikWizard";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  content: {
    display: "flex",
    flexFlow: "column nowrap",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%"
  }
}));

const initialValues = {
  forename: "",
  surname: "",
  optionalComments: ""
};

const StepOne = ({ setFieldValue }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [optional, setOptional] = useState(false);
  const displayOptional = optional ? null : "none";

  const handleOptionalChange = () => {
    setFieldValue("optionalComments", "");
    setOptional(!optional);
  };

  return (
    <Box className={classes.content}>
      <FormikTextField
        fullWidth
        size="small"
        variant="outlined"
        name="forename"
        label="Forename"
        type="text"
      />
      <FormikTextField
        fullWidth
        size="small"
        variant="outlined"
        name="surname"
        label="Surname"
        type="text"
      />
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={optional}
              onChange={handleOptionalChange}
              name="optional"
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label="Optional"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormikTextField
        style={{ display: displayOptional }}
        fullWidth
        size="small"
        variant="outlined"
        name="optionalComments"
        label="Comments"
        type="text"
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Wizard
        title="My Wizard"
        open={true}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onCancel={() => {
          return;
        }}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
        }}
      >
        <StepOne />
        <StepTwo />
      </Wizard>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Alternative

To use `setFieldValue` in Formik, the easiest way would be to have the all input elements within the `<Formik></Formik` tags. You could conditionally render the input elements based on what step you're on as follows. This gives the inputs a direct access to `setFieldValue` so you can call `setFieldValue("optionalComments", "")` on the `Switch` input which will clear the comments on each toggle. Although this may mean you'll have a longer form, I don't think this is necessarily a bad thing.

```
<Formik>
    <Form>
        {step === 1 && <div>
            // Insert inputs here
        </div>}

        {step === 2 && <div>
            <TextField 
                onChange={(event) => setFieldValue("someField", event.target.value)}
            />
             <Switch
              checked={optional}
              onChange={() => {
                  setFieldValue("optionalComments", "");
                  setOptional(!optional);
              }}
              name="optional"
              color="primary"
            />
        </div>}
    </Form>
</Formik>
```